Minimum Jaccard similarity
Suppose that we have three sets $A$, $B$ and $C$ and that the following inequalities hold for the Jaccard similarities:
$J(A,B) \geq \gamma$,
$J(A,C) \geq \gamma$.
The question now is what is the minimum Jaccard similarity $J(B,C)$ between $B$ and $C$?
If e.g. $\gamma = 0.9$, then the minimum Jaccard similarity can't be zero. My guess is that the minimum similarity in this case is $2\gamma - 1$, but I can't find a proof. Does anyone know the answer? If so, how does the proof look?

Your guess is right. There is an easy proof in this paper: "A note on the triangle inequality for the Jaccard distance" by Sven Kosub [https://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/abs/pii/S0167865518309188].
